# *nix shellscript: Get disk usage on multiple OSs

Tags: shell-script, disk-space, df

I am trying to get the usage-percentage for a given disk in a system. The program I have to write will be a `bash` shell script. The script has to work on Debian, Arch, and Mac OS X.

My current approach is to do a `df` and grep for the usage percentage. The problem is that the output of `df` differs on these systems. I want to avoid `if os==Arch elseif os == Debian…`as far as possible.

Is there a solution which avoids distinguishing the OS?

#### Example output for each operating system / version of `df`:

Mac

```
Filesystem    512-blocks       Used Available Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2     179032136  106162416  72357720    60%  13334300  9044715   72%   /
```

Debian

```
Filesystem    1K-blocks  Used     Available  %used Mounted on
/dev/hdv1       20480000 8423436  11016564   44%   /
```

Arch

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        5160576 813420   4085012  17% /
```

So Arch and Debian are pretty the same. It may also be a problem that the labels are maybe printed in different languages.

Comment: Could you post the df output on the different OSs so we can compare please?

Comment: Edited the post to show some examples.

Comment: It isn't so much the OS but the source of the `df` utility. Most (all?) linux & BSD distributions use df from the GNU coreutils package. Mac OS X doesn't. OS X was originally built from a BSD-like interface onto its kernel but the utilities don't track closely with the GNU versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for all three `df` outputs:

```
df | awk '/\//{print $1,$(NF-1)}'
```

This is the output on each of the examples you posted:

```
/dev/disk2 72%
/dev/hdv1 44%
/dev/root 17%
```

EXPLANATION:

The `awk` command looks for lines that contain a `/` (so, ignores the headers) and prints the first (`$1`) and penultimate (`$(NF-1)`) fields. If you want *only* the usage percentage, do this:

```
df | awk '/\//{print $(NF-1)}'
```

---

**Update:**

My answer above will give you the `%iused` field on the Mac `df` output. If you want the `Capacity` instead, do this (works on all three again):

```
df | perl -ne '/\// && do {/(.+?)\s.+?(\d+%)/ && print "$1 $2\n"}'
```

which also prints the first field (the non-greedy `(.+?)`, terminated by `\s`) and the *first* percentage number (`(\d+%)`, preceded by the non-greedy `.+?`).

Comment: This does not work for the mac example, as the first number with % suffix is the capacity

Comment: @kwave, that makes no difference. I am not using the `%` character anywhere. What I am doing is printing the **next to last** field which is always the percentage used. Did you try it? It works as advertised with the Mac output you have posted.

Comment: Hang on, in the Mac do you want the capacity or the inodes% ? Is that number ever different? Anyway, see my updated answer if you want the capacity and not the inodes.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly messier but probably more universal solution is

```
df | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*[^0-9]\([0-9]*%\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

which displays the first “word” on the line (the filesystem device name) and then looks for a sequence of digits followed by a `%`.  Specifically, it looks for the ***last*** such string.

[Oops: it will also display a mangled subset of the header
(i.e., the first line, with the column headings).]

---

**Update:**

```
df | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*[^0-9]\([0-9][0-9]*%\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

fixes the glitch with the header row, and

```
df | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\) [^%]*[^0-9]\([0-9][0-9]*%\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

captures the *first* percentage number field. 
In particular, on the Mac, this will capture the `Capacity` column rather than the `%iused` column.

Comment: This does not work for the mac example, as the first number with % suffix is the capacity

Comment: Oops.  I fixed it.